# I/flutter (12605): [firebase_auth/unknown] null - Error in Android studio when clicking on Register button

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, user-registration

I am trying to sign up a user in a Registration form using form - textformfields. Though when I click on Register, the console throw this error. I haven't found a similar thread. I have already added in my main Firebase.initializeApp()

but still it is not working.

The error is just this line

*I/flutter (12605): [firebase_auth/unknown] null*

Any help?

Thanks

Here is my registration screen code:

```
bool showSpinner = false;

class RegistrationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/registration-screen';
  @override
  _RegistrationScreenState createState() => _RegistrationScreenState();
}

class _RegistrationScreenState extends State<RegistrationScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.midGrey,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: <Widget>[
                Hero(
                  tag: 'logo',
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 0),
                    height: 290,
                    child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 48.0,
            ),
            ModalProgressHUD(inAsyncCall: showSpinner, child: AuthForm()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthFormState createState() => _AuthFormState();
}

class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
  final _emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String email;
  String password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(40),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      elevation: 8.0,
      color: AppColors.formBackgroundColor,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Form(
          key: _formkey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                controller: _emailcontroller,
                key: ValueKey('email'),
                autocorrect: false,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                    return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration:
                    kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Enter your email'),
                onSaved: (value) {
                  email = value;
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 8.0,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _passwordcontroller,
                key: ValueKey('password'),
                obscureText: true,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 5) {
                    return 'Password must be at least 5 characters';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                    hintText: 'Enter your password'),
                onSaved: (value) {
                  password = value;
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 24.0,
              ),
              RoundedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    showSpinner = true;
                  });
                  try {
                    final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email, password: password);
                    if (newUser != null) {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, AuthScreen.routeName);
                    }

                    setState(() {
                      showSpinner = false;
                    });
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                },
                colour: AppColors.midGrey,
                title: 'Register',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact, complete error message and its stack trace.

Comment: Hi Frank the only line of error I get in the console is 
I/flutter (12605): [firebase_auth/unknown] null